# Как сериализовать List<T> в xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

Есть класс `DB`, который я хочу сериализовать в `xml`.

```
public class DB
{
    [XmlElement("Nomer")]
    public string Nomer { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Raspolojenie")]
    public string Raspolojenie { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Whois")]
    public string Whois { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Start")]
    public string Start { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("End")]
    public string End { get; set; }
}
```

Пробовал такой вариант, но выдает ошибку.

```
List<DB> listDB = new List<DB>();

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DB));
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, listDB); 
string xml = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Comment: Мне кажется что таких вопросов тут куча. И не обязательно `List<T>`, любой обьект сериализируется по одной и той же схеме.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вы объявляете сериализатор с **типом вашего класса**:

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(DB));
```

И передаете список объектов вашего класса:

```
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, listDB);
```

Попробуйте объявить сериализатор с **типом списка вашего класса**:

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DB>));
```

[Проверить!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KVGoXc)